# Propagation speed of isobaric mixing?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, weather

### Question

So I was trying to model the following. Lets say I have a gas box where the partition box has just been removed as shown below:

[image]

Both gases are of the same species the difference being the gas on the left is of less temperature $T_0$ than the temperature of the gas on the right $T_1$. What is the earliest someone at the extreme left can detect a temperature change after the opening of the gas? (Assume an idealized system such that the box not play a role in heat conduction and there is no change in pressure $P$)

### My attempt

The average velocity in left side is:

$$ \langle v_0 \rangle = \sqrt\frac{{3 k_b T_0}}{m}$$

where, m is mass of the gas. Similarly the average velocity in the right side is:

$$ \langle v_1 \rangle = \sqrt\frac{{3 k_b T_1}}{m}$$

At the partition after the first set of collisions we know the relative velocity $\langle |v_{rel}| \rangle$ obeys:

$$ \langle |v_{rel}| \rangle = \langle |v_1 - v_0| \rangle \leq \langle |v_1| \rangle + \langle |v_0| \rangle  = \sqrt\frac{{3 k_b}}{m} (\sqrt{ T_0} +  \sqrt{ T_1}) $$

We now associate a fictious temperature (maximum possible) at the partition for the relative velocity called $T'_{1}$ compatible with what we know from the maxwell distribution:

$$ \langle |v_{rel}| \rangle= \sqrt{2} \langle | v | \rangle$$

Thus,

$$\sqrt\frac{{6 k_b T'_1}}{m} = \sqrt\frac{{3 k_b}}{m} (\sqrt{ T_0} +  \sqrt{ T_1})  $$

Since the ideal gas law must be obeyed. The density $\rho_1$ at the partition is:

$$ \rho'_1 k_b T'_1 =  P $$

Now consider the second set of collisions (the red line):

[image]

Again introducing a fictious temperature $T'_2$ for this layer, we get:

$$ \sqrt{2 T'_2} = \sqrt{T'_1} + \sqrt{T_0} $$

and the density there is:

$$ \rho'_2 k_b T'_2 =  P $$

We also know the [number of collisions](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Supplemental_Modules_(Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry)/Kinetics/06%3A_Modeling_Reaction_Kinetics/6.01%3A_Collision_Theory/6.1.04%3A_Collision_Frequency) at the $i$'th layer is given by:

$$ dN = {\rho'}_{i}^2 A \sqrt{\frac{6 k_b T'_{i}}{m}} dt$$

We know the average mean free path at the $i$'th layer is given by $l_i$. Thus,

$$  l_i dN = dx  $$

Substituting our expression:

$$ l_i dx = {\rho'}_{i}^2 A \sqrt{\frac{6 k_b T'_{i}}{m}} dt$$

Or:

$$  v = \frac{1}{l_i}{\rho'}_{i}^2 A \sqrt{\frac{6 k_b T'_{i}}{m}} $$

This can be [integrated](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2888976/the-definite-integral-problem-with-a-twist) to given us a propagation speed of:

$$  v =  \langle \frac{1}{l_i}{\rho'}_{i}^2 A \sqrt{\frac{6 k_b T'_{i}}{m}} \rangle $$

with

$$\langle k_i \rangle = 
\lim_{N \to \infty}\sum_i^N k_i /N$$